# Login redirects to home page after 2.2 update

Tags: redirect

Since updating to Craft 2.2, my front-end login form now redirects to the home page.

The intended behaviour is to just reload the page that the visitor was on when they logged in.

In Craft 2.1 I achieved this by omitting the hidden redirect field. Any idea how to prevent members from being kicked to the home page now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Brad said the new default behavior is for users to be redirected wherever [postLoginRedirect](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#postLoginRedirect) is set to (if a `redirect` param was not in the POST data).

You can get your old behavior back by adding that hidden `redirect` param though, set to [craft.request.getPath()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getPath):

```twig
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ craft.request.path }}">
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. I really don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

Craft 2.2 introduced the [postLoginRedirect](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#postLoginRedirect) config setting which affects not only where users on the front-end of the site get redirected to after logging in (defaults to the home page), but where they get sent if they visit the front-end login page while they are logged in.